# amsmath+pdfx causes overdot misplacement

Tags: amsmath, pdfx

The concurrent use of `amsmath` and `pdfx` results

[image]

On the other hand, if I comment out either `pdfx` or `amsmath`, the dot is positioned correctly:

[image]

What causes this glitch? The document class and the compiler have no effect on it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx} % generate PDF/A-compliant document
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   \dot{A} \geq 0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

PS: I know that `amsmath` is not needed for the *equation* environment; that was just an example, in my real document, I use the *align* environment.

Comment: This is basically a shot in the dark, although I've looked at the source code for `amsmath`.  `amsmath` does different things with `\dot` depending on whether or not it is defined.  Try inserting this before `\usepackage{amsmath}`:  `\let\dot\undefined`.  Not tested and not guaranteed.

Comment: This returns errors from `amsmath.sty`, e.g. `Paragraph ended before \@tempb was complete. \noindent\ignorespaces##1\par` and `Too many }'s. }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [patch given here](https://gist.github.com/yuw/a31936370647d0044eeb4e47f3ae913f)  and let me know how well it works.
I'll be adding it to the coding for  `pdfx v1.6.4` .

Comment: Thanks, it gives visually identical results both with `amsmath` enabled and disabled.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you do \showoutput as below, then you will find that the letter A is included twice: once before and once after the accent character. Thus text-extraction gets it twice too. I've come to the conclusion that this kind of patch just isn't good enough. So we must use an /ActualText replacement instead.

Answer (score 3):

If I add `\showoutput`, the relevant part for `\dot{A}` is

```
....\hbox(9.20636+0.0)x7.50002, shifted 168.75, display
.....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 A
.....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x-7.50002
......\kern -7.50002
.....\vbox(9.20636+0.0)x7.50002
......\hbox(6.67859+0.0)x0.0, shifted 2.36111
.......\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 _
......\kern-4.30554
......\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x7.50002
....\penalty 0
```

Without `pdfx`, I get

```latex
...\hbox(9.20636+0.0)x7.50002, shifted 168.75, display
....\vbox(9.20636+0.0)x7.50002
.....\hbox(6.67859+0.0)x0.0, shifted 3.75005
......\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 _
.....\kern-4.30554
.....\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x7.50002
......\OML/cmm/m/it/10 A
...\penalty 0
```

The macro `\dot` is defined in terms of `\mathaccentV`, which is

```latex
> \mathaccentV=macro:
#1#2#3#4#5->\ifmmode \gdef \macc@tmp {\macc@depth \@ne }\setbox \z@ \hbox {\let
 \mathaccentV \macc@test \let \use@mathgroup \@gobbletwo \let \select@group \@g
obblethree \frozen@everymath {}$#5$}\macc@tmp \ifnum \macc@depth =\@ne \global 
\let \macc@nucleus \@empty \mathaccent "\accentclass@ \else \@xp \macc@nested \
fi #2#3#4{#5}\macc@nucleus \else \@xp \nonmatherr@ \csname #1\endcsname \fi .
```

The package `pdfx` changes it to

```latex
> \mathaccentV=macro:
#1#2#3#4#5->#5{\mathsurround =\z@ \relax \everymath {}\mathchoice {\setbox \z@ 
\hbox {$\displaystyle #5$}\kern -\wd \z@ }{\setbox \z@ \hbox {$\textstyle #5$}\
kern -\wd \z@ }{\setbox \z@ \hbox {$\scriptstyle #5$}\kern -\wd \z@ }{\setbox \
z@ \hbox {$\scriptscriptstyle #5$}\kern -\wd \z@ }}\AMS@mathaccentV {#1}{#2}{#3
}{#4}{\phantom {#5}}.
```

This explains the difference in the outputs shown above: normally, the accent is typeset *first* and uses the `\mathaccent` features, which include looking at the `\skewchar` of the font, for properly placing the accent on slanted letters. With `pdfx` the accentee is typeset in a box and later the accent is placed above it; this loses all information about correct placement and TeX centers the accent over the box.

Why is `pdfx` doing so I don't know. But there's no workaround except resetting `\mathaccentV` to the default, which might result in a noncompliant PDF.

Comment: Text extraction, using Unicode combining accents, requires the accent character to come after the base. You cannot satisfy sensible Accessibility or Archivability requirements without this.